# Is possible to create a react component and use it in other projects html?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I was wondering before starting to do it, if is posible to create a react proyect(i need to do a forum widget) code it on react and the compile it and put the .js output file in other proyect, not with react the other proyects uses php symphony and twig, would be as easy as importing the script and adding a ?

Comment: Yes you can, if you compile your react project (for instance using webpack) then it can result in a single js file for use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done. The bundle of a react app is a complete js with everything that you need to run it. At the end you only import one js file in your html. I recommend you use a bundler library like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to generate a minified bundle and apply other functionality before creating the final bundle.